# OpenDeploy Base Server hangs up with starting deployment

Tags: linux, teamsite, interwoven, autonomy

I'm managing Autonomy/Interwoven OpenDeploy Base Server.

OS:RHEL5.3

TSVer.:TeamSite6.7.2

ODVer:OpenDeploy7.1

OpenDeploy Base Server process sometimes hangs up when starting deployment.

following message are out in [od.log]

*** glibc detected**  /var/od-home/OpenDeployNG/jre/bin/java: double free or corruption (!prev): 0xb01721d8 **

does anyone know about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teamsite 6.7.1+ doesn't support Vintela (VAS) for users or groups on Linux.

I've seen same error in the iwtrace.log, the fix is to make sure that VAS (Vintela)  is not used for authentication of users and groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answering this minor question! but We don't use Vintela on thie TS/OD Server. 
This error has occurred in opendeploy base process. 
but TeamSite process could be related with this error. 
because opendeploy is deploying a file managed in TeamSite.

Comment: from the error log you showed, looks as though java is running something that trying to use VAS. i'd check your authentication methods used for OD and TS. If files you are deploying are coming from Teamsite, then there will be some authenication going on..

Comment: Thank you for your helpful hint, we keep going!